# How should we use template with std::accumulate in a function to return right type by cosidering template not "init"

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The type of return from `std::accumulate` depends on the "init" i.e. if it is integer it will return integer and if it is double it will return double.

I have a template function for sum like this:

```
T mean(std::vector<T> vector)
{
    T sum = std::accumulate(vector.begin(), vector.end(), X);
}
```

What should I put instead of `X`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `T{}`, which is a default-constructed `T`. e.g.

```
T sum = std::accumulate(vector.begin(), vector.end(), T{});
```

If you need it to be intialized with some initial value, you can

```
T sum = std::accumulate(vector.begin(), vector.end(), T{some_initial_value});
```

or

```
T sum = std::accumulate(vector.begin(), vector.end(), static_cast<T>(some_initial_value));
```

Comment: It's wrong method. It leads to overflow. For example: if you have vector of unsigned __int16 and you want to find sum of these elements std::accumulate will store result in  unsigned __int16 ( max value 65535 ). But what if sum of elements is more than 65535?